# Reshape dataframe using ID

Tags: python, dataframe, transpose

I have an issue by adding an ID to my dataframe.

The index of my dataframe is a datetime and then I have columns with the same variable for each ID. I would like to keep the index but having one column for each variable and adding a column giving the ID.

What I have :

[image: Dataframe number 1]

What I want :

[image: Dataframe wanted]

Here my try :

[image: Result]

````
ID_List = df.columns.str.split(' ').str[5].tolist()[1:]
ID_List = [sub[:-1] for sub in ID_List]
print(ID_List)

Tag_List = nacelle1.columns.str.split(':').str[1].tolist()[1:]
Tag_List = ['LOCAL_TIME'] + Tag_List
print(Tag_List)

df.columns = Tag_List

df_tr = df.transpose()
new_header = df_tr.iloc[0] #grab the first row for the header
df_tr = df_tr[1:] #take the data less the header row
df_tr.columns = new_header #set the header row as the df header
df_tr['ID'] =ID_List```
````

Answer (score 0):

As a beginner in pandas, I am not sure how to get the perfect answer but you have to use df.stack() in one way or another.

Comment: Thx ! I'll have a look if it could work to solve my problem 
​​​​​​​